# Problems with Flurry Crash Analytics

Tags: analytics, crash-reports, flurry

I think Flurry crash analytics service is not working properly. It is reporting some errors, so far so good. The problem is that they are including an initial symbolication and it doesn't make any sense:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a3005b0 +[Protocol load] + 663
    1   UIKit                               0x343993f5 0x342b1000 + 951285
    2   UIKit                               0x34586a39 0x342b1000 + 2972217
    3   UIKit                               0x342bd82f 0x342b1000 + 51247
    4   UIKit                               0x342bc293 0x342b1000 + 45715
    5   UIKit                               0x342c71e7 0x342b1000 + 90599
    6   UIKit                               0x342c6db3 0x342b1000 + 89523
    7   UIKit                               0x342b4801 0x342b1000 + 14337
    8   UIKit                               0x342b411b 0x342b1000 + 12571
    9   GraphicsServices                    0x35fa85a3 0x35fa2000 + 26019
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x35fa81d3 0x35fa2000 + 25043
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x32481173 +[__NSCFLocale automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:] + 17062
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x32481117 +[__NSCFLocale automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:] + 16970
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x3247ff99 +[__NSCFLocale automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:] + 12492
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x323f2ebd -[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + 500
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x323f2d49 -[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + 128
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x35fa72eb 0x35fa2000 + 21227
    17  UIKit                               0x34308301 0x342b1000 + 357121
    18  myApp                              0x000f962d __mh_execute_header + 50733
```

I uploaded its respective dsym file but no significant change.

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x8
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a3005b0 +[Protocol load] + 663
1   UIKit                               0x343993f5 0x342b1000 + 951285
2   UIKit                               0x34586a39 0x342b1000 + 2972217
3   UIKit                               0x342bd82f 0x342b1000 + 51247
4   UIKit                               0x342bc293 0x342b1000 + 45715
5   UIKit                               0x342c71e7 0x342b1000 + 90599
6   UIKit                               0x342c6db3 0x342b1000 + 89523
7   UIKit                               0x342b4801 0x342b1000 + 14337
8   UIKit                               0x342b411b 0x342b1000 + 12571
9   GraphicsServices                    0x35fa85a3 0x35fa2000 + 26019
10  GraphicsServices                    0x35fa81d3 0x35fa2000 + 25043
11  CoreFoundation                      0x32481173 +[__NSCFLocale automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:] + 17062
12  CoreFoundation                      0x32481117 +[__NSCFLocale automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:] + 16970
13  CoreFoundation                      0x3247ff99 +[__NSCFLocale automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:] + 12492
14  CoreFoundation                      0x323f2ebd -[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + 500
15  CoreFoundation                      0x323f2d49 -[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + 128
16  GraphicsServices                    0x35fa72eb 0x35fa2000 + 21227
17  UIKit                               0x34308301 0x342b1000 + 357121
18  myApp                               0x000f962d main + 145 (main.m:17)
```

Does anyone know how to disable their symbolication service. What I want is to download a plain crash report so I can do my business and make my own symbolication locally.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813522/symbolicating-an-ios-7-crash-report-using-flurry-crash-analytics

Answer (score 0):

Just download the crash report from Flurry and import it in XCODE and resymbolicate.

If you dont want flurry to symbolicate your crash reports, In the TARGETS sections in XCODE set 
Build Settings -> Build Options -> Debug Information Format = DWARF

Comment: My crash reports from Flurry won't import into XCode. Now what?